# Xlrd list index out of range

Tags: list, indexing, xlrd

I'm just starting to explore Xlrd, and to be honest am pretty new to programming altogether, and have been working through some of their simple examples, and can't get this simple code to work:

```
import xlrd

book=open_workbook('C:\\Users\\M\\Documents\\trial.xlsx')
sheet=book.sheet_by_index(1)
cell=sheet.cell(0,0)
print cell
```

I get an error: list index out of range (referring to the 2nd to last bit of code)
I cut and pasted most of the code from the pdf...any help?

Comment: I'd also recommend that you use the sheet_by_name method on the workbook, since it will make your program flexible. It would be able to handle someone who rearranges the worksheets or inserts new ones.

Comment: @BenMordecai: `sheet_by_name` is of course the way to go if you expect sheets with particular names. It doesn't handle the case where one sheet is expected but the creators are wilfully inconsistent in their choice of sheet name.

Comment: You could always check it against book.sheets or iterate through and find the one you need. You're ultimately have a handful of choices: the sheet in the right position, the sheet with the right name, or check each sheet and test based on the data you want to find.

Answer (score 1):

I would play around with it in the console.

Execute each statement one at a time and then view the result of each. The sheet indexes count from 0, so if you only have one worksheet then you're asking for the second one, and that will give you a list index out of range error.

Another thing that you might be missing is that not all cells exist if they don't have data in them. Some do, but some don't. Basically, the cells that exist from xlrd's standpoint are the ones in the matrix `nrows` x `ncols`.

Another thing is that if you actually want the values out of the cells, use the `cell_value` method. That will return you either a string or a float.

Side note, you could write your path like so: `'C:/Users/M/Documents/trial.xlsx'`. Python will handle the `/` vs `\` on the backend perfectly and you won't have to screw around with escape characters.

Comment: `maxrows` etc is wrong. Use the `Sheet` sttributes `nrows` and `ncols`.

Comment: You're right. I wasn't thinking about the name of the attribute itself, I was thinking about which cells are defined at a given time. I'll edit for correctness.

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> I get an error: list index out of range (referring to the 2nd to last
>   bit of code)

I doubt it. How many sheets are there in the file? I suspect that there is only one sheet. Indexing in Python starts from 0, not 1. Please edit your question to show the full traceback and the full error message. I suspect that it will show that the `IndexError` occurs in the 3rd-last line:

```
sheet=book.sheet_by_index(1)
```